# Declaring a variable using the var keyword inside a function. Why is it undefined, behind the scenes

Tags: javascript, var, hoisting

I'm a newbie and I want to make sure that I understood the hoisting with var correctly.

```
var a = 2;
var x = function() {
   console.log(a);
   var a = 1;
};
x();
```

When the "x" function is invoked, the answer that I get is "undefined";
So, the engine sees that in the function scope of "x" there is a variable "a" and assigns it to "undefined";

If we take out the variable "a" inside the function:

```
var a = 2;
var x = function() {
   console.log(a);
}
x();
```

Then we get the answer "2", because the engine looks if there is a variable "a" inside the function "x", since it doesn't find it here, it looks in the outer/parent/global scope for the variable "a", and finds it.

Did I get everything right?

Comment: Basically, that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you got it pretty much right. Just a small note for when you say:

> So, the engine sees that in the function scope of "x" there is a variable "a" and assigns it to "undefined";

It's more like: only declarations are hoisted, not initializations. And declared but non-initialized variables default to `undefined`. See https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp#midcontentadcontainer.

For the second function, yes, that's correct—first it looks inside the function's scope, and then, since it can't find it, it looks inside the parent scope, then the parent's parent, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access before initialization inside local memory of function x().
Hoisting happens inside function local memory and x will be initialized with undefined.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33932003)

Answer (score -1):

In short, when you do this:

```
var a = 2;
function() {
   console.log(a);
   var a = 1;
}
```

Javascript "hoists" your variable declarations before it interprets your code, basically converting your code to this:

```
var a = 2;
function() {
   // there a now new "a" variable which is undefined
   var a; 
   console.log(a);
   a = 1;
}
```

When JS resolves a variables, it crawls up the function scopes until it finds a variable matching the one you want. When the inner "a" variable is hoisted, it essentially overrides your outer "a" variable. Back in the day it was good practice to declare all your variables "up top" to prevent any weird unexpected issues from hoisting. The hoisting problems do not exist with `const` and `let` - which is why most code today is written with those instead of `var`.

Comment: thank you for the reply. What about the second piece of code? Does it look first inside the function and after not finding it, looks outside the function?

Comment: OP is aware of hoisting, he even uses the word in his question.

Comment: @weltschmerz sorry for my ignorance what is OP?

Comment: You're the OP—"original poster." My comment was directed at Ryan.

Comment: I see that and have removed the link. Though, I still explain what's actually happening from the interpreter... even in my original answer. Not really worth the downvote IMO, but whatever.